# Insert Operation Code Review

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have method that returns 1 if an operation is successful and 0 if an operation is failed. I am using entity framework to perform database operations.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int InsertEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        //insert code
        if(employee.EmployeeId > 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it good practise to rewrite above method like below.

```
public enum StatusMessage { Success, Error };

public static class Status
{
    public static StatusMessage GetStatus(this int status)
    {
        if (status > 0)
        {
            return StatusMessage.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusMessage.Error;
        }
    }
} 

public class Employee
{
    public StatusMessage InsertEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        //insert code
        return employee.EmployeeId.GetStatus()
    }
}
```

Please suggest me a better way to write above code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not return a `boolean`? You should change it to an `Enum` when you have more than two states.

Comment: I think that question is more suited for CodeReview because you do not have an actual problem you need help with, this is just an opinion based question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually consider returning `void` and throwing an exception if the operation fails.

If you would rather return a status indicator then you should rename your method to something like `TryInsertEmployee`. In this case I would simply return a `bool` to indicate the success. The problem of course is that you cannot attach any more information as to why the operation was not completed successfully. With an exception, you can.

The reason for both of these points is:

**Throw an exception if the method cannot perform the action that its name describes.**

Comment: Good arguments, better solution. +1

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please share an example

Answer (score 1):

I would return a `Boolean`.  True/False -> Success/No success

- Returning an Int could create confusion. Some assume that you're returning an Id.
- Use an Enum, when more than one states could be returned.